# Unable to clone repository

Tags: java, intellij-idea, clone, git-clone, cloning

I just wanted to clone a project from github but everytime I try, the [loading bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZp1G.png) goes forever. I already had a few problems with git and intellij (altough I didn't change any settings) but everytime I could fix it somehow but this time it worked fine for the last couple of weeks but now it stopped working from one to another day. Here are my [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNNQ1.png) if needed.

I already tried to clear the cache but it didn't work. Tried to look up fixes on the internet but couldn't find anything that can help me. Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Path to git executable does not look entirely correct. I assume you use GitForWindows, and there the correct executable to use should be `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe`. Try specifying it in settings instead.

As for the clone process, it might appear to be stuck while actually being very slow, or it might be some authentication prompt issue - e.g. git asks for credentials on some wrong tty and cannot get a response. Using an executable

If changing the executable does not help, check the [IDE logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) to see if there are some unhandled errors there. You cam also submit a request to [JetBrains support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/?intellij-idea) with the logs attached.